# How many variables do you need to be complete for $\Sigma^0_n$?

Tags: logic, computability, turing-machines

The [arithmetic hierarchy](https://m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) is a structure on sentences in first order logic. It has a particular relationship with computability, due to [Post’s Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem).

In most discussions of the arithmetic hierarchy, it’s assumed that you have access to every formula $\phi$ in first order logic. But what if you don’t? Specifically, what if we define $\Sigma_{n,m}^0$ to be the usual set $\Sigma_n^0$ except you only have formulae with a total of $m$ variables ($n\leq m$).

What’s the computability theoretic power of this set? Is there a number of variables that is sufficient to get the full power of $\Sigma_n^0$? What if we set $m=n$?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, there is a $\Sigma_0$ coding of finite sequences. So you could say something like $\varphi(x)$ is $\exists y_1,\dots,y_n < x\varphi_{\rm code}(y_1,\ldots,y_n,x)\land\psi(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, and the whole thing is still $\Sigma_n$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila can you say that in different words? I’m not sure I see the point.

Comment: Since you can encode $n$-tuples in a $\Sigma_0$ way, moving from $\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ to $\varphi'(x)$ by adding that $x$ codes $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ will not change the complexity, just the number of free variables.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ah yes, but I’m interested in fixing the *total* number of variables, not the free variables.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. I misread. I'll leave the comments, so the next person who's confused will have clarifications available. :)

Comment: I think it is possible that the answer to this question may depend on how exactly you are setting up the language of arithmetic. Assuming you start with a language like $\{0,1,+,\times,<\}$, then to get Post's theorem to work, you have to allow yourself to have bounded quantifiers "for free". However, if you give yourself a symbol $\varphi(e,x,s)$ and interpret this as "$\Phi_e$ on input $x$ halts in $\leq s$ steps", then (I think) you don't need bounded quantifiers anymore and then the halting set is defined by a formula with exactly one quantifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Matiyasevich's Theorem, the universal $\Sigma_n$ formula is equivalent to one of the form

$\exists y_1 \forall y_2 \cdots Q y_n Q^* y_{n+1} \phi( x, \bar y)$,

where $Q$ and $Q^*$ are the appropriate quantifier and bounded quantifier, respectively, and $\phi$ is free of quantifiers. This means you only need $n+1$ variables to get the full power of $\Sigma_n$---with the caveat, as @James has brought up, that your language should be the same one used by Matiyasevich.

Removing one variable reduces your computational power to that of $\Sigma_{n-1}$.  For example, if $\phi$ is quantifier-free, the set $\{x :\exists y \phi(x,y)\}$ is decidable by first using calculus to find upper and lower bounds on the possible $y$, and then checking each value by hand.

Comment: Excellent! I had meant to revise this question, but this is a good enough answer to the one that I posed that I shall let it stand. I might make another post with a particular language in mind.

Comment: Welcome to MSE by the way! I see you’ve posted several good answers about logic already. I hope you stick around.... we could always use more logicians.

Comment: Also, do you know of a language where this linear bound isn’t true? Where it takes quadratically many (or some other function of $n$) variables to achieve universiality?